# compose files provided as list in Ansible Playbook provide Configuration Error on execution

Tags: docker-compose, ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

### Description

I wish to bring a couple of containers using distinct `compose.yml` files instead of a single `docker-compose.yml` file. Within each `docker-compose.<service>.yml` file I have a Jinja template that fills out the the template file depending on which services are mentioned in a `vars/main.yml`

A simple example:

#### `docker-compose.chronograf.yml.j2`

```
version: "3"
services:
  chronograf:
    image: chronograf:{{ services.chronograf.version }}
    container_name: chronograf
{% if 'influxdb' in services %}
    depends_on:
      - influxdb
{% endif %}
    environment:
      - BASE_PATH=/chronograf
{% if 'influxdb' in services %}
      - INFLUXDB_URL=http://influxdb:8086
{% endif %}
    hostname: chronograf
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.chronograf-router=chronograf-router@file"
      - "traefik.http.routers.chronograf-router.service=chronograf@file"
    security_opt:
      - "no-new-privileges:true"
    volumes:
      - chronograf:/var/lib/chronograf
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
volumes:
  chronograf:
```

#### `docker-compose.influxdb.yml.j2`

```
version: "3"
services:
  influxdb:
    container_name: influxdb
    image: influxdb:{{ services.influxdb.version }}
    environment:
      - INFLUXDB_HTTP_AUTH_ENABLED=true
      - INFLUXDB_REPORTING_DISABLED=true
      - INFLUXDB_DATA_QUERY_LOG_ENABLED=false
      - INFLUXDB_HTTP_LOG_ENABLED=false
      - INFLUXDB_CONTINUOUS_QUERIES_LOG_ENABLED=false
    hostname: influxdb
    security_opt:
      - "no-new-privileges:true"
    volumes:
      - influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro

volumes:
  influxdb:
```

the `services` above is defined as follows:

```yaml
services:
  chronograf:
    version: 1.9-alpine
  influxdb:
    version: 1.8-alpine
```

Jinja will be able to add the `depends_on` part of the Compose YAML if `services.influxdb` exists (which it does)

### Bringing the Stack Up using ansible

within a playbook I have the following:

```yaml
---
- host: all

tasks:
  - name: Copy Services Compose Files
    template:
      src: "services/docker-compose.{{ item }}.yml.j2"
      dest: "/home/test/influxstack/docker-compose.{{ item }}.yml"
    with_items: 
      - "{{ services.keys() }}"

  - name: Docker Compose with multiple Compose Files (v2)
    community.docker.docker_compose:
      project_name: influxstack
      project_src: /home/test/influxstack
      files:
        - "docker-compose.{{ item }}.yml"
      state: present
    with_items: 
      - "{{ services.keys() }}"
```

### Error

Upon dry-running / running on the local machine (by creating a directory `/home/test/influxstack` I keep getting the following error:

```
TASK [pacedge : Docker Compose with multiple Compose Files (v2)]

ok: [localhost] => (item=influxdb)
failed: [localhost] (item=chronograf) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "chronograf", "msg": "Configuration error - Service 'chronograf' depends on service 'influxdb' which is undefined."}
```

Ansible is unable to keep the sequence in order for `files` as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_compose_module.html#parameter-files)

I have also tried adding:

```
 {{ services.keys() | reverse(sort=True) }}
```

to try and bring InfluxDB up but I keep getting the same error

### System Information

#### ansible

```bash
ansible [core 2.12.5]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/shantanoo/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/shantanoo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/shantanoo/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /home/shantanoo/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18) [GCC 9.4.0]
  jinja version = 2.10.1
  libyaml = True
```

#### docker compose

```
Docker Compose version v2.6.1
```

```
pip list | grep -i "docker"
docker                 4.1.0
docker-compose         1.25.0
dockerpty              0.4.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two separate `docker-compose.yaml` files; if you're starting them separately, you can't have dependencies between services in one file and services in another.

The way you've written your playbook, you are effectively doing this:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.chronograf.yaml up
docker-compose -f docker-compose.influxdb.yaml up
```

That's because you're using `with_items` loop: you're running the `docker_compose` task once for each in the list.

That won't work, because when `docker-compose` is bringing up the influxdb stack, it's not aware of the chronograf stack. The only way this can work is if you run `docker-compose up` referencing both files on the command line, as in:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.chronograf.yaml -f docker-compose.influxdb.yaml up
```

The equivalent change to your playbook would be:

```
  - name: Docker Compose with multiple Compose Files (v2)
    community.docker.docker_compose:
      project_name: influxstack
      project_src: /home/test/influxstack
      files: "{{ compose_files }}"
      state: present
    vars:
      compose_files: >-
        {{ services.keys() |
           map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', 'docker-compose.\1.yaml')
        }}
```

We've removed the loop, and we're instead constructing a list of
filenames and passing that as the `files` argument.

---

Tested using...

`playbook.yaml`:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    services:
      service1:
      service2:
  tasks:
    - name: Docker Compose with multiple Compose Files (v2)
      community.docker.docker_compose:
        project_name: influxstack
        project_src: .
        files: "{{ compose_files }}"
        state: present
      vars:
        compose_files: >-
          {{ services.keys() |
             map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', 'docker-compose.\1.yaml')
          }}
```

`docker-compose.service1.yaml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  service1:
    image: docker.io/alpine:latest
    command:
      - sleep
      - inf
```

`docker-compose.service2.yaml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  service2:
    image: docker.io/alpine:latest
    command:
      - sleep
      - inf
```

Running:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml
```

Results in:

```
$ docker-compose -p influxstack -f docker-compose.service1.yaml -f docker-compose.service2.yaml ps
         Name             Command    State   Ports
--------------------------------------------------
influxstack_service1_1   sleep inf   Up
influxstack_service2_1   sleep inf   Up
```

Comment: Appreciate it. I was a bit lost because of some lack of documentation on the `files` parameter, I was under the impression that a list of compose files under `files` would be able to perform the equivalent of `-f ` in compose command. The documentation is a bit misleading as it mentions the following statement `Files are loaded and merged in the order given.` (specifically the word __merged__)

Comment: I mean, that's correct: a list of compose files under `files` *is* the equivalent of multiple `-f` arguments to `docker-compose`, but you weren't passing a list: you were providing a single file at a time. The files are loaded and merged in the order given: they are combined into a single effective docker-compose.yaml file.